# Definition of the infimum of a set in terms of a minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have the following intuition regarding the relationship between the infimum of a set:

Let's define the set of accumulation points of a set called $S$ as $S'$, its closure:$\bar{S}=S \cup S' $, and x the infimum of that set. Since the minimum of an ordered set S is defined as its greatest lower bound, I understand that $x \in S $ or $x \in S'$, i.e. $x \in S \cup S'$

So, is it right to define the infimum in the following way?:

$inf \{s: s \in S\}=min\{s: s \in S \cup S'\} = min\{s : s \in \bar{S} \} $

Comment: Are you talking about bounded sets of reals (and of accumulations points in the usual topology)? There will be counterexamples if you work with the set of all rational numbers (instead of with reals). There will be other examples, if you do work with the reals, but with the Sorgenfrey (lower limit) topology. Welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not state what the space is,
I'll assume the space is a linear order topology.

No it is not right to define inf S as min $\bar S$.
inf S = min $\bar S$ is a theorem to be proved. 
 
Theorem.  If min $\bar S$ exists then inf S = min $\bar S$ 
Proof.  Since S subset $\bar S$, min $\bar S$ is a lower bound for S.

Assume a is a lower bound for S and min $\bar S$ < a. 
Thus exists x in $\bar S$ with x < a.
As (<-,a) is an open set containing x, exists y < a with y in S.
Since that's a contradiction,
there are no lower bounds for S greater than min $\bar S$.
Thus min $\bar S$ = inf S.